# Semantic Web - immediate benefits

Tags: semantic-web

Are there any immediate benefits of implementing semantic web features in a website - and does google really pay attention to rdf markup?

I have read on and off over the last couple of years but nothing major appears to be happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any immediate benefits of implementing semantic web features in a website

There are already a few [success stories of the Semantic Web](https://web.archive.org/web/20150425041134/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/1533/what-are-the-success-stories-of-the-semantic-weblinked-data).

> does google really pay attention to rdf markup?

Take a look at [what Google says about RDFa](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146898&topic=1088472&ctx=topic) and how it produces [rich snippets](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170&topic=1088472&ctx=topic) out of that.

Answer (score 2):

Currently the biggest incentive IMHO is:

> "Search engines including Bing, Google, Yahoo! and Yandex rely on this markup to improve the display of search results, making it easier for people to find the right web pages." -- http://schema.org/

More people/eyeballs, more traffic => more subscriptions/products sold/advertisement money.

You said: "nothing major appears to be happening". I disagree, right now schema.org is something major happening.